# ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

Tags: express, ejs

This is my whole code. I am trying to locate on my page.ejs page through `/insta/:id` but it is showing the error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')`.

I want to get id that `uuidv4()` will be giving but instead it is returning username. And also I want to get the specific post through the id(which is getting username value and not the generated id) but my post variable didn't get any specific post in it.

## This is index.js

```
const express=require("express");
const app=express();
const path=require("path");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const port=3000;

let posts=[
    {   
        username:"evablue@2",
        image:"/post1.jpg",
        content:"Enjoying at this beautiful beach :)",
        tags:"",
        id:uuidv4(),
    },
    {
        username:"purple_whale",
        image:"/post2.jpg",
        content:"A pic should be clicked before digging in <**>",
        tags:"@shresDrawMystry, @riddhiMolala",
        id:uuidv4(),
    },
    {
        username:"nature'sBaby",
        image:"/post3.avif",
        content:"Love clicking beautiful moments.",
        tags:"@bankpyt",
        id:uuidv4(),
    },
    {
        username:"butterscoth#Love",
        image:"/post4.jpg",
        content:"It's Holi.Woooooohoooo.",
        tags:"",
        id:uuidv4(),
    },
    {
        username:"coffeeLover",
        image:"/post5.jpg",
        content:"Explored a new Cafe.",
        tags:"@RelaxCafe",
        id:uuidv4(),
    }
]

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:true }))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.set("views",path.join(__dirname,"/views"));

app.get("/insta",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("home.ejs",{ posts });
})
app.get("/insta/:id",(req,res)=>{     
    let {id}=req.params;
    let post=posts.find((p)=> id===p.id );
    console.log(req.params);
    res.render("page.ejs",{ post });
})


app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("Port 3000 is listening requests");
})
```

## This is page.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?        family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,400,0,0" />
    <title><%= post.username %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="dp">
            <img src="<%= post.image %>">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <h5><%= post.username %></h5>
            <button>Follow</button>
            <button>Message</button>
             <button><span class="material-symbols-outlined">person_add</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')` from your `page.ejs` file when you try to access `username` here:

```
<title><%= post.username %></title>
```

The `post` object is empty because of the way you are using the `uuid` library.

When you create your `posts` array, the `uuidv4()` function generates **a new value every time your server restarts**:

```js
let posts=[
    {   
        username:"evablue@2",
        image:"/post1.jpg",
        content:"Enjoying at this beautiful beach :)",
        tags:"",
        id:uuidv4(), // id:2d98e533-769e-4352-83ea-c4fdbc516d73
    },
    {
        username:"purple_whale",
        image:"/post2.jpg",
        content:"A pic should be clicked before digging in <**>",
        tags:"@shresDrawMystry, @riddhiMolala",
        id:uuidv4(), // id:6064012d-cf4f-4445-88c8-e62d25153c98
    },
    ...
];
```

How do you know which value to pass to your `app.get("/insta/:id"` route?

Your router looks fine but you would need to add `console.log('posts:', posts)` straight after you create the array so you can actually see what value the `uuidv4()` has added for each `id` within the `posts` array. You could then navigate to:

```
'http://localhaost:3000/insta/6064012d-cf4f-4445-88c8-e62d25153c98'
                            //^^ Replace this with one of the values shown in the console.log('posts:', posts)
```

However, this is very cumbersome and you should just use a database like MySQL or MongoDB. I appreciate that will be another technical challenge but you won't be able to rely on an array forever. Read the docs and have faith in yourself!